# Saving history while have the transiton

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, browser-history

I'm trying to accomplish a task where I have a transition that leads to another page. The problem is that the history is not saved when you use javascript to change pages (of course). I am trying to have the ability to navigate the pages thru the back button on the browser. How can I transition with history saved?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<a href="#" onClick="back()">Back</a>

<script>
    function back(){
        if(history.length === 1){
            window.location = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/"
        } else {
            history.back();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 has a [History_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) that you can use to navigate while saving states.

You can use methods such as

```
history.pushState({page: 1}, "title 1", "?page=1")
history.pushState({page: 2}, "title 2", "?page=2")
history.replaceState({page: 3}, "title 3", "?page=3")
```

to manipulate history as you programatically navigate your application.